# SQL Server 2012 Hierarchical query issue

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, hierarchical

I am struggling to get a Hierarchical recursive query to work, I found some samples on the net but they all show the manager-employee level which does not seem to work for me. I have this issue, I have a list of organisations and I need to extract the ID of all employees. So I need to provide the top level employees, then find all the branches and all the employees for the branches. I tried adapting the examples and get excessive recursion errors, any help very gratefully received !

Ok so the structure I have is a contact table like this

SerialNumber
Name

Where the entry in the contact table is either a head office, a branch or an employee

and a relationship table
Parent
Child
DescriptionID

In this instance the head office is a parent with child entries that are employees or branches defined by DescriptionID, so I need to provide a SerialNumber as a parent to anchor then find all the branches and employees under this parent (defined as child in the relationship), then add all the employees of all the branches (child of the branch where the branch serialnumber is a parent in the relationship table)

Thanks

Comment: Could you post some sample data and the desired output based on it?

Comment: Please provide your table structure, some sample data, expected outcome and what you have tried

Comment: what you mean with 'does not seem to work for me'? it is not suitable? it is the right one but produces errors? you don't know how to implement it?

Comment: I have edited the question to try and add this information now